# Which one is correct definition of subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Q: the number of subring of ring of integer $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite (T/F)

I know that subring no need exist multiplicative unit in subring. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n\mathbb{Z}$ is subring of $\mathbb{Z}$, the answer above question is T.

But some textbooks says the definition of subring exists multiplicative unit in it(Serge lang, Bourbaki, ...). Then following this definition, the only subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. therefore the answer above question is F.

Which one is correct definition of subring?

(Above question was given in the teacher certification exam in korea, this exam didn't specify which textbooks in study.)

Comment: I'm sorry to say the exam question isn't well posed. You're exactly right in thinking either answer could be correct. Personally I would say there are no proper subrings of $\mathbb Z$ but I have many friends who would disagree, and say each of the (infinitely many) ideals is a subring. There is no "correct" answer

Comment: When you think about it, while some might in certain obvious senses be better than others, definitions are not either correct or incorrect: they are just definitions.